# Optimization, global variables and memory-barriers

Tags: c++, optimization, interrupt-handling, memory-barriers, data-race

In the following example the variable `v` is not accessible from outside this TU. So the compiler can optimize the loop in `main()` to an empty loop. This is done with `-O3`, but with `-Os` it remains a loop with the load of `v` outside the loop, so that it is effectively an endless loop without effect.

The function `isr()` could be optimized away, but is not since it should resemble an ISR and therefore hast the `used` attribute.

If one changes `v` to an external visible global, the assemble code remains the same!

How can the compiler reason, that `v` remains unmodified in this case?

Inserting a memory-barrier sure fixes that in both cases. But why isn't it suffcient to make `v` external visible?

```
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>

//int v; 
namespace {
    int v; 
    void isr() 
        __asm__("__vector_5") 
        __attribute__ ((__signal__, 
        __used__
        )); 
    void isr() { 
        v += 1; 
    }
}

int main() {
    while(true) {
//        _MemoryBarrier();
        if (v == 42) { 
            v += 1; 
        }
    }    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4j7En41sE

Comment: Infinite loop without side-effects - is UB, data race - is UB. Access to variable from different threads without synchronization - is data race. So, if you don't have `volatile` specifier or synchronization, then you have UB and everything can be optimized out.

Comment: If one inserts a different volatile access into the loop (no UB anymore), the access to `v` is still optimized away. There are no concurrent actions here, so no UB due to data race.

Comment: An interrupt handler interrupting the loop could be seen as happening during `main`'s accesses to `v`.  Optimizations preserve the behaviour of single-threaded code, but not of signals / interrupts unless you use `volatile sig_atomic_t v`.  See also [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478)

Comment: As stated above, making `v` external visible is not sufficient to let the compiler reason, `v` might be modified. One must insert a call to a non-inline function, to achieve that. If the function is inline / defined in the same TU and does not access `v`, the compiler again can do the optimization.

Comment: The strange thing is that although `isr()` is inline, modifying `v` and marked as `used`, this is handeld different than a call to a non-inline `foo()`.

Comment: This looks like the attribute `used` is online to prevent the compiler from removing the function `isr()` at all. The attribute `used` does not mean that it takes place in the flow-analysis as somehow called.